# Issue with my PHP MySQL and AJAX code. Trying to select from a database where a name equals a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, onchange

I was following [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) found in the w3schools regarding php, mysql, and ajax. I edited the code to fit my needs, but I am unable to display information pulled from mysql. In all honesty, I'm not even sure if anything is being pulled from mysql. I do not receive any errors. The mysql database contains the id, name, and rating.

Here is my html page called results.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function showName(str) {
 if (str=="") {
 document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="";
 return;
 } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else { // code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","phpresults.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="Name" onchange="showName(this.value)">
 <option value="">Select a Book:</option>
 <option value="Book 1">Book One</option>
 <option value="Book 2">Book Two</option>
 <option value="Book 3">Book Three</option>
 <option value="Book 4">Book Four</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
 <div id="info"><b>Select from above</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php page called phpresults.php

```
<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost","username","userpw");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db("dbname");

$sql="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
   echo $q;

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>BOOK NAME</th>
<th>RATING</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["rating"] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As of right now, when I make a selection, I am only displayed with BOOK NAME and RATING and nothing underneath it. When I echo $q I am shown the value of what I selected in the dropdown. I am trying to display the name and rating of a book based on the value selected in the dropdown.

EDIT:
I believe there is something wrong with this part of the code.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
```

When checking for errors, by using this

```
if (!$result) {
  die('Could not query: ' . mysqli_error($result));
}
```

I receive "Could not query:" but no error.

Comment: Most likely your query is not returning anything and hence the while loop is not executing.  Try echoing your $sql content and then try it from the mysql command line to see if the query returns any results.

Comment: you are using myqli_query and connect with mysql_connect, mixing mysqli_* with mysql_*

Comment: Peter, I echoed $sql and received this when I clicked Book One: SELECT * FROM star_rating WHERE name = 'Book 1'

I ran that statement in the mysql command line and it returned the desired results, but it still does not seem to work in my code.

Comment: Another suggestion, don't use ANY w3schools tutorials.  There are apparently great at search engine optimization, but the content is typically dated, incomplete, or just flat wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is mixing **`mysqli_`** and **`mysql_`** function calls.

Don't do that, because that will cause errors.

Replace those **`mysql_`** function calls with references to the appropriate **`mysqli_`** functions.

(And I'm not at all surprised that the w3fools site would have examples with mixed calls like this.)

Comment: Silly me. I updated my code above. I even tried using all mysql function calls but was still not successful. I also tried changing '(while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {' to '(while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {'

Answer (score 0):

I removed the $sql variable and entered the select statement directly into the mysqli_query. I also made sure that all of my function calls were mysql_ since mysqli_ was not displaying the results.

Here is my working php code.

```
<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","username","userpw");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name = '".$q."'") or die(mysql_error());


echo $q;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo" <th>Rating</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["rating"] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```